# Have more than one toolbar without having to set supportActionBar or actionBar?

Tags: android

I have multiple fragments side-by-side in my activity. Each of these fragments have their own toolbar at the top. For that reason, I would like to avoid using `setActionBar()` as I have two toolbars. However, if I don't have an `ActionBar`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is never called even if I call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. Is there a way to have two toolbars and add menus to them without setting an ActionBar nor calling `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onCreateOptionsMenu` or any of those APIs.

If you have your own Toolbar, use the Toolbar APIs. Namely, each Fragment can use [inflateMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#inflateMenu(int)) to add items to its Toolbar, then use [`setOnMenuItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#setOnMenuItemClickListener(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener)) to set a click listener for when one of those MenuItems are clicked.